# i get this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: vue is not defined when i declare a global variable

Tags: laravel, vue.js

The code works fine until i declare the global filter Uncaught ReferenceError

```
require('./bootstrap');

window.Vue = require('vue');

import { Form, HasError, AlertError } from 'vform'

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

//global components
Window.Form = Form;
Vue.component(HasError.name, HasError)
Vue.component(AlertError.name, AlertError)
```

this is where the error originates : vue filter produces uncaught errors reference, vue is not defined

```
vue.filter('capitalize', function (text) {
    return text.toUpperCase();
})

// explicit installation of Router via Vue.use()
Vue.use(VueRouter)
```

Comment: please do i need to rearrange my code

Comment: have you tried `Vue.filter....` instead of  `vue.filter`? `Vue` not `vue`

Comment: i fixed the error by capitalizing the Vue.filter();

Comment: glad to hear it worked.